# PHPExcel : how can use indexed colors with 'color' key?

Tags: phpexcel

I'm new with PHPExcel and I wonder how I could use indexed colors instead of rgbs for the key 'color' :
        $style_array = array(
        'font' => array( 
                    'bold' => true, 
                    'size' => 14 ,
                    'color'=> array('rgb'=>'FF000000'
        )
        );

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question as I read closely the file Color.php. There's a special fonction for my purpose, and I used like this :
$mycolor_index = 46 ;//Excel index for a nice orange
and in the array :
..
'color' => PHPExcel_Style_Color::indexedColor($mycolor_index)
..

Thank you for reading.